# Content Type of Folder incorrectly set in Document Set

Tags: document-library, content-type, folder, sharepoint-on-prem, document-set

I'm experiencing an issue that is directly related to this question posted here (https://collab365.community/forum/topics/sub-folder-content-types-set-wrong-in-document-set-library/):

> I have a SharePoint Online Document library that contains only the out-of-the-box “Document Set” content type. Using the Ribbon I create a new Document set and then open it. From the ribbon I then click the “New Folder” button and a new folder is created as expected.
>
> Examining the properties of the new folder I find that SharePoint has assigned the Content Type to be “Document Set” and not “Folder” as I would expect. SharePoint does provide the ability to change the content type to Folder using the Content Type dropdown selector in the Edit properties form.
>
> How can I configure the Library to use “Folder” content type instead of “Document Set” content types when users create new folders?

---

I don't see a solution.

The *Document Set* settings lists *Document* as the only "Content types allowed in the Document Set".  *Folder* isn't even an option on the Document Set settings page, only *Discussion* and *Summary Task*, which are both children of the Folder content type, but then why wouldn't *Folder* be listed? On the Site Content Types page there exits a "Folder Content Types" group and *Folder* is listed (Item is the parent)?

To further this peculiarity requires looking at the edit properties form.  When going into the newly created "folder", which has the Content Type set to *Document Set*, the Content Type can be changed to *Folder*.  I found this peculiar, since (again) *Folder* isn't listed as the "Content types allowed in the Document Set" on the Document Set Settings page.

Has anyone experienced this that can lend a hand?  I have different instances of SharePoint on-prem and some create a Folder as expected and some create the Document Set.  I can't determine the differences between their settings, or if this is just corruption.  I need to determine if this is a setting that can be changed (perhaps farm/SCA-only?) and how to do that.

Thanks in advanced